# Displaying variable as a class name in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to incrementally display divs using Jquery, but I have a problem with getting the right syntax for displaying the variable as a class. Here is my code:

```
var mydiv_id = 'wacek_'+$a; /wacek_1, wacek_2, etc 

$("<div class="+mydiv_id"></div>").appendTo('body');
$( ".col-sm-4" ).append( $( '.'+mydiv_id ) );
$('.'+mydiv_id).hide();
```

I cannot get this right, any help would be greately appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused. First you are adding to `body`. Then you fetch added element and append it to `$( ".col-sm-4" )` which can be multiple. Then you again fetch same element and hide it. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? I mean, least you can chain hide part: `.append( $( '.'+mydiv_id ).hide() )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use

```
$("<div class='"+mydiv_id+"'></div>").appendTo('body');
```

Instead of

```
$("<div class="+mydiv_id"></div>").appendTo('body');
```

Please check below snippet for more understanding.

```js
var $a = '1';
var mydiv_id = 'wacek_'+$a; //wacek_1, wacek_2, etc 

$("<div class='"+mydiv_id+"'></div>").appendTo('body');
$( ".col-sm-4" ).append( $( '.'+mydiv_id ) );
$('.'+mydiv_id).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var mydiv_id = 'wacek_'+$a; /wacek_1, wacek_2, etc 

$("<div class="+mydiv_id+"></div>").appendTo('body');
$( ".col-sm-4" ).append( $( '.'+mydiv_id ) );
$('.'+mydiv_id).hide();
```

Try this. one + was missing in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgnruqm1/3/)

You had a small syntax error:

```
$("<div class="+mydiv_id"></div>").appendTo('body');
```

should be

```
$("<div class='"+mydiv_id+"'></div>").appendTo('body');
```

And I don't understand why you are appending your HTML to the body first and then into your DIV. It is also easier to chain your jQuery functions. Means instead of this:

```
$("<div class='"+mydiv_id+"'></div>").appendTo('body');
$( ".col-sm-4" ).append( $( '.'+mydiv_id ) );
$('.'+mydiv_id).hide();
```

you can use this:

```
$("<div class='"+my_id+"'>s</div>").appendTo('.col-sm-4').hide();
```

With the same result.

Comment: Thank you, there is a reason - the div that you suggest to append to doesnt exist as it is dynamically created later.

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating the variable with string and are missing the `+` after the variable. You need it on both sides if a string comes again after the variable. Also, don't forget to enclose the created string in `"` (or `'`):

```
$("<div class='" + mydiv_id + "'></div>")
```

In the both statements below, the variable is the last expression - so you don't need an additional `+` - so this is correct:

```
$('.' + mydiv_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This is not a proper comment. Use `//` for comments. 
var mydiv_id = 'wacek_'+$a; //wacek_1, wacek_2, etc 

// Missing your quotes around your class attribute. 
// missing concatenation. Also, instead of appending it to the body
// and then appending it to the your .col-sm-4, just
// append it to the column in the first place: Change 2nd line to:
$("<div class='"+mydiv_id+"'></div>").appendTo('.col-sm-4');

// Remove third line..
$('.'+mydiv_id).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

So as the other answers suggest, you have a syntax error with appending the class. The code can be done in a different manner so you do not have to worry about building the string. [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes). Also there is no reason to append the element to the document, select the element, and reappend it. You have a reference to the element when you create it, so just use that reference.

```
var myDiv = $("<div></div>", {
        "class" : mydiv_id
    });
myDiv.hide()
myDiv.appendTo(".col-sm-4");
```

or in one line:

```
var myDiv = $("<div></div>", {
        "class" : mydiv_id
    }).hide()
    .appendTo(".col-sm-4");
```

Comment: Thank you, there is a reason - the div that you suggest to append to doesnt exist as it is dynamically created later.

Answer (score -1):

use this
concatinate all the string one bye one

```
 $("<div class="+mydiv_id+">"+"</div>")
```

Or

```
$("<div class="+mydiv_id+"></div>")
```